# Is there a way to dynamically fetch on the graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to write one decoder for *both* training (should pass gradient down to the encoder) and beam-search mode (single steps from python, sadly, so not linked to the encoder directly).

Ideally, something like this would work:

```
decoder(beamSearchFlag_boolPlaceholder, initalState_fromEncoder, initialState_placeholder, input):
        initialState = tf.cond(beamSearchFlag_boolPlaceholder, 
        lambda: initialState_placeholder,
        lambda: initalState_fromEncoder)

... = cell(input, initialState)
```

But with cond() TF still needs to resolve the dependencies of both branches. The _fromEncoder branch is executed when beamSearchFlag==False, even without effect, and that's a big part of unnecessary graph. Is there a way around this?